# keysexposed resource qualifier

Tags: android, android-resources

Can somebody explain what the `keysexposed` resource qualifier means? [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#KeyboardAvailQualifier) is completely incomprehensible: *warning, don't read if you have a volatile brain!*

> **keysexposed:** Device has a keyboard available. If the device has a
>   software keyboard enabled (which is likely), this may be used even
>   when the hardware keyboard is not exposed to the user, even if the
>   device has no hardware keyboard. If no software keyboard is provided
>   or it's disabled, then this is only used when a hardware keyboard is
>   exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I haven't used this anywhere but I'm gonna ride on the back of simple English semantics to make sense of the documentation extract you quoted.

`keysexposed:` Lol! Volatile brain.

`Device has a keyboard available.` This is just stating that it's assuming the device on which the app's running has a hardware keyboard.

`If the device has a software keyboard enabled (which is likely),` The devices which have hardware keyboard sometimes have the "slide-in" keyboards, or other options to disable the hardware keys. `this may be used even when the hardware keyboard is not exposed to the user` meaning the keyboard is in the "slid-in" state (hence not visible to the user). `even if the device has no hardware keyboard.` and this could also be used in the obvious case of the device not having a hardware keyboard at all.

`If no software keyboard is provided or it's disabled, then this is only used when a hardware keyboard is exposed.` If the software keyboard is disabled, in that case to whichever resource you add this qualifier, would be shown only if and when the hardware keyboard is exposed to the user (that is, it's in the "slid-out" state).

So basically adding this qualifier to a resource would mean it would be used all the time if a software keyboard is enabled. But if the software keyboard is unavailable/disabled, then it would only be used when the hardware keyboard is "exposed" to the user, that is slid out.

Comment: I equalized it, no worries :) In fact your answer deserves more than 1 up-vote. Thanks for brief answer.